# Import android project in ADT Eclipse from github

Tags: android, eclipse, github, adt

I'm trying to import an android project from github into ADT Eclipse but it doesn't find any projects in the repository when I clone it. The repo is clearly an android application project (from looking at the source) but no project is found to import. My steps are as follows:

1. In "Package explorer" right-click and select "Import"
2. Import project from Git.
3. Enter uri: https://github.com/moagrius/MapViewDemo
4. Just import master.
5. When cloning is done the following dialog shows up:

[image]

6. When choosing "Import existing projects" the below dialog shows:

[image]

Why are no projects found to import!? How can I import the projects into eclipse?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The eclipse project files (.project and .classpath) are not part of the github repository so you can't just import it into Eclipse.

Easiest way to fix that is probably to create a new Android project yourself and then copy the files from the github repo into it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of Selecting the "import existing Projects", just Choose 'Android Project from Existing Code'.

- For the 'root directory' click on 'browse' and select the place where you imported your project. (that master one and maybe someother)

Press Finish

Answer (score 2):

**7 Easy  steps to import Github android projects in to ADT**

1. create repository in Github .
2. select the HTTP clone url .
3. Clone the project in to local system using clone command.
4. import the project from the cloned path in to adt.

5.Select  the imported project and click right button.

6.Click Team->share project.

7.Click Finish.

==========================

For Commiting the changes

1. Select the project and click right button
2. Click Team and press Commit , write you comments , click push and commit..