# Importing github android source to eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven

I have been trying to import https://github.com/github/android  project to my eclipse. I just cannot seem to import it without any errors, and also the directory structure of main doesn't show any source code after importing. It will be of great if anyone can help me out with the whole process.

P.S. - This is not a possible duplicate of [Importing a GitHub project into Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760115/importing-a-github-project-into-eclipse) or [Import android project in ADT Eclipse from github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431920/import-android-project-in-adt-eclipse-from-github) . I have tried everything, and I think the source code is somewhat 'mavenized' ?

Comment: How are you importing it? What options are you using?

Comment: Using Egit to pull it from github. It isn't working

Comment: This is the error I am getting *The type com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files*

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

- Use `git clone` to clone the project somewhere in your local storage;
- Open Eclipse (in Java perspective and with Android SDK installed), and choose "File" > "New" > "Other...";
- Then choose "Android" > "Android Project from Existing Code";
- In "Root Directory", pick the app folder of the repository you just cloned;
- Tick "Copy projects into workspace";
- Press "Finish".

However, keep in mind you need to have the android version the manfest is asking for. Don't forget about that.

Answer (score 0):

i can able to import the same project :

Steps followed:

Eclipse: File-> Import> Git-> Project from Git-> Clone URI->

Clone URL: https://github.com/github/android.git

in case required : Git plugin available at : http://www.eclipse.org/egit/download/